# Interchange y, x to x, y with geopandas (python) or QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, shapely, geopandas

I realized that the order of my geopandas dataframe is wrong, it has y, x instead of x, y.

This makes it difficult to use with other modules that needs exactly x, y type of coordinates. Is there any function in *geopandas* to interchange the coordinates without the need to enter in each geometry element, geometry type and change coordinates one by one? If not is there a shapely function to do it similarly instead of collecting all points one by one and change them?

*More info*: I have a geodataframe composed of a lineStrings (shapely object) in the geometry field for each row. If it's easier to do it in QGIS, I could also do it there.

Comment: Where did you get your original dataframe? I would switch the coordinates as early in the workflow as possible, i.e. before you create a geodataframe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To swap (x,y) for any Shapely geometry type, here is a general function. It also preserves z coordinates (if present):

```
def swap_xy(geom):
    if geom.is_empty:
        return geom

    if geom.has_z:
        def swap_xy_coords(coords):
            for x, y, z in coords:
                yield (y, x, z)
    else:
        def swap_xy_coords(coords):
            for x, y in coords:
                yield (y, x)

    # Process coordinates from each supported geometry type
    if geom.type in ('Point', 'LineString', 'LinearRing'):
        return type(geom)(list(swap_xy_coords(geom.coords)))
    elif geom.type == 'Polygon':
        ring = geom.exterior
        shell = type(ring)(list(swap_xy_coords(ring.coords)))
        holes = list(geom.interiors)
        for pos, ring in enumerate(holes):
            holes[pos] = type(ring)(list(swap_xy_coords(ring.coords)))
        return type(geom)(shell, holes)
    elif geom.type.startswith('Multi') or geom.type == 'GeometryCollection':
        # Recursive call
        return type(geom)([swap_xy(part) for part in geom.geoms])
    else:
        raise ValueError('Type %r not recognized' % geom.type)
```

For example:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiLineString

# POINT Z (1 2 3) -> POINT Z (2 1 3)
swap_xy(Point(1, 2, 3))

# MULTILINESTRING ((1 2, 3 4)) -> MULTILINESTRING ((2 1, 4 3))
swap_xy(MultiLineString([[(1, 2), (3, 4)]]))

# Map the function to a geopandas geometry column
table.geometry = table.geometry.map(swap_xy)
```

Comment: While this is done well, it's probably safer / quicker / more general to use the `shapely.ops.transform` function as in the answer by MCMZL.

Answer (score 11):

`shapely.ops.transform` module allows passing a function to operate on coordinates. Therefore if you want to swap x, y coordinates in a GeoDataFrame you can use :

```
import shapely

gdf.geometry.map(lambda polygon: shapely.ops.transform(lambda x, y: (y, x), polygon))
```

To account for 3D geometries (or as in my case, a mix of 2D and 3D), add the optional z=None parameter this way:

```
gdf.geometry.map(lambda myGeom: shapely.ops.transform(lambda x, y, z=None: (y, x, z), myGeom))
```

BTW, this should work for all kinds of geometries (lines, points, polygons)

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to interchange coordinates by means of [**Swap XY**](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/swapXY/) plugin in QGIS. Just select the layer and click the button.

[image]

Changes are carried out in place so that you may need to backup.

Answer (score 4):

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import geopandas

def swap(x):
    coords = list(x.coords)
    coords = [Point(t[1], t[0]) for t in coords] #Swap each coordinate using list comprehension and create Points
    return LineString(coords)

df.geometry = df.geometry.map(swap) #Apply the function to the geometry of dataframe df
```

Answer (score 4):

QGIS 3.2 has a native "Swap X and Y coordinates" algorithm in the Processing Toolbox. This may come in handy if you need a GUI solution which works with all geometry types.