# Determining the Coordinate system for set of points

Tags: coordinate-system, point, coordinates, wgs84, uruguay

I have the following set of points.

```
X   Y
618263.27   6153928.04
601343.35   6492627.09
670869.41   6448843.47
499463.38   6201245.29
569373.30374535 6140971.32153155
579069.9206 6142002.1728
587240.73   6169831.91
405985.13292033 6525416.77610315
691827.43837039 6134141.18687316
580728.8799 6138533.0341
571591.04   6150195.46
583096.23   6149466.76
419626.75   6453768.35
554301.86   6152931.57
593045.66   6152752.66
596090.5903 6205196.6006
575312.8149 6138980.0326
579242.01   6149289.44
837479.57081977 6387138.37567135
468821.22   6208240.19
612621.23   6152083.74
571903  6176635.82
628421.29   6548098.13
628421.29   6548098.13
....
```

According to the dataset reference they are in the format WGS84 / UTM zone 21S.
But it does not match the [specification](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-21s/) of that format.

I've tried plotting them on a map using GeoPandas, but haven't been able to.
I think they are in the wrong format, but I know very little about GIS.

In what format do you think the dots are? Is there any transformation to make to the points to make them valid?

Comment: What about these values makes you think they aren't in UTM 21S?

Comment: when placed on a map (using geopandas) they are outside the coordinate system (all points should be within Uruguay). I didn't find any online map with that coordinate system, but for example you can use https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=32721&t_srs=4326&x=618263.2700000&y=601343.3500000 to transform them and google maps to draw them.

Comment: I use QGIS, set the project CRS to EPSG:29181 (SAD69/ UTM 21S) and paste a few of your coordinates, all of them are inside of Uruguay. So the coordinates seem to be correct

Comment: Here is result for EPSG:5382 (SIRGAS ROU / UTM zone 21S) at epsg.io for the first coordinate: http://epsg.io/map#srs=5382&x=618263.27&y=6153928.04&z=9&layer=streets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [projfinder](http://projfinder.com/). For instance, when I paste provided coordinates `(618263.27,6153928.04)` in Uruguay

[image: projfinder]

then I will end up with several options.

I assume that your CRS is mostlikely the ["EPSG:32721 | UTM zone 21S"](https://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-21s/). Exactly what was mentioned by @Vince.

And extending the @Vince's comment I suppose when you try plotting these coordinates in GeoPandas you may accidentally swap your coordinates, i.e. x instead of y and vise versa, so please check his thread [Interchange y, x to x, y with geopandas (python) or QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291247/interchange-y-x-to-x-y-with-geopandas-python-or-qgis).

Otherwise, you may check several more, e.g. ["EPSG:32321 | WGS 72 / UTM zone 21S"](https://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32321/), ["EPSG:31981
SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 21S"](https://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31981/) or ["EPSG:29191
SAD69 / UTM zone 21S"](https://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/29191/).